# zomato like restaurant page or Recycler view with item repeatition and heading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, multiple-columns

How to create a recycler view wuth following type as shown in image below:

Bucket Meals Image:

[image]

Chicken Image:

[image]

As shown above in Bucket Meals Image there is a category named `Chicken` having 2 items, while as shown in Chicken Image, there are 4 items in category named `Burgers`.

So my question is, How to create such a list with repeating items and not the heading until other category data comes in.

Textual Menu :

**Chicken**

- Hot and Crispy Chicken
- Smoky Chicken

**Burger**

- Veg longer Burger
- Veg Ginger Burger
- Chicken Zinger Burger
- Chicken Zinger Meal

The data looks like :

```
"category": [
{
  "name": "Panner Thali",
  "id": "1511",
  "desc": "This thali has price only 100 with 4 chpati, i plate rice, 1 sabji, 1 raiyta,1 daal...",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Panner with 2 roti and 1 sabji",
      "id": "13931",
      "real_price": "10",
      "description": "This is the testing panner with 2 roti and 1 sabji thali",
      "price": "20.00"
    },{
      "name": "Panner Veg Thali",
      "id": "13930",
      "real_price": "20",
      "description": "This is the testing description..",
      "price": "30.00"
    },{
      "name": "just for test 21",
      "id": "54502",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "This is the testing description..",
      "price": "30.00"
    },{
      "name": "just for testing",
      "id": "81742",
      "real_price": "100",
      "description": "This is the testing description..",
      "price": "110.00"
    }
  ]
},{
  "name": "latest cat",
  "id": "1602",
  "desc": "hi",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "test5",
      "id": "21067",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "just test",
      "price": "60.00"
    },{
      "name": "test4",
      "id": "21066",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "just test",
      "price": "60.00"
    },{
      "name": "test3",
      "id": "21065",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "just test",
      "price": "13.00"
    },{
      "name": "test2",
      "id": "21064",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "just test",
      "price": "14.00"
    },{
      "name": "test1",
      "id": "21063",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "just test",
      "price": "15.00"
    },{
      "name": "just test",
      "id": "14854",
      "real_price": "50",
      "description": "",
      "price": "60.00"
    },{
      "name": "test6",
      "id": "21072",
      "real_price": "50",
      "description": "test",
      "price": "60.00"
    },{
      "name": "test7",
      "id": "21073",
      "real_price": "50",
      "description": "testt",
      "price": "60.00"
    },{
      "name": "test",
      "id": "81806",
      "real_price": "0",
      "description": "testing",
      "price": "20.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

For every category add a new cardview, while for every items inside category add a textview containing that item details.

Comment: Use a expandablelistview, or check this library https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Answer (score 0):

For each category you can use a recylerview. Otherwise you take an extra field for menu type. Then short them on menu type. Then take two type of layout: one for item type and another for item. Now based on "type" or "index", add the layout to recyclerview.

Use multiview Adaper for recyclerview. Recylerview has one most powerfull feature of multiple view adaper. sample code as below:
package com.diary.kumud.mydiary;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

/*addapter for dashboard*/
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DashBoardModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;
    int total_types;

    public static class SingleBrickViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titleTxt, descTxt;
        ImageView iconImgView;

        public SingleBrickViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            this.descTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            this.iconImgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        }
    }

    public static class DoubleBrickViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView iconImgView;
        TextView titleTxt;

        public DoubleBrickViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.iconImgView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            this.titleTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        }
    }

    public MultiViewTypeAdapter(ArrayList<DashBoardModel> data, Context context) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;
        total_types = dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case Model.DOUBLE_BRICK:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.smallbricks, parent, false);
                return new DoubleBrickViewHolder(view);
            case Model.SINGLE_BRICK:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bigbrick, parent, false);
                return new SingleBrickViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        switch (dataSet.get(position).tilesType) {
            case 0:
                return Model.DOUBLE_BRICK;
            case 1:
                return Model.SINGLE_BRICK;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        DashBoardModel object = dataSet.get(listPosition);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.tilesType) {
                case Model.DOUBLE_BRICK:
                    ((DoubleBrickViewHolder) holder).titleTxt.setText(object.titletext);
                    setImage(mContext,object.imagName,((DoubleBrickViewHolder) holder).iconImgView);
                    break;
                case Model.SINGLE_BRICK:
                    ((SingleBrickViewHolder) holder).titleTxt.setText(object.titletext);
                    ((SingleBrickViewHolder) holder).descTxt.setText(object.descText);
                    setImage(mContext,object.imagName,((SingleBrickViewHolder) holder).iconImgView);
                    break;
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startMyActivity(dataSet.get(listPosition).actionActivity);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String imgName, ImageView myImgView){
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();
        int resID = res.getIdentifier(imgName , "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
        myImgView.setImageDrawable(drawable );
    }

    private void startMyActivity(String ActivityName){
        String activityToStart = ActivityName;
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(activityToStart);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, c);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
            Log.e("no activity","Activity not found");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how to populate one activity with different data? I mean when category comes in then add heading and when items comes in add it inside that category?

Any example..? or code sample?

Comment: Can you send me a link of image, i.e. final output you can get with this code, that you provided.

Comment: Inside onCreateViewHolder what is  case Model.DOUBLE_BRICK ? what is DOUBLE_BRICK? and Model

Comment: that is just two type of value to differentiate for two view. Model.DOUBLE_BRICK is havving value 0 and Model.SINGLE_BRICK is having value 1.

Comment: I've found an example.. This might help https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki